# How to implement in-app update feature when new version of app is available in Google Play Store

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, in-app-update

I have been struggling with a concept regarding in-app update notification to the user in Flutter framework. I mean when you deploy a new version of an existing mobile app in Google Play Store or in the Apple App Store, the user should get the notification on opening the app to use. As the user clicks the update button, the new version of the app should be downloaded from the respective stores.

I tried to use upgrader package for the above feature, but I did not get the expected result.

Comment: Updating an app is based on user store preferences.
On the other hand, you can display a modal, conditioned on the version of the app, informing the user of an available update and redirecting to the store.

Comment: You can try this dependency : **in_app_update: ^4.1.4**

Comment: hi @VincentDR, Thank you for suggestion. but How to fetch the current version of installed app on device and existing version of app in google play store based on which I can show the modal pop up

Comment: hi @DarshanKachhadiya, thank you for the suggestion, let me try out this..

Answer (score 0):

Use following packages:

1. [in_app_update](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update) package for **Android**.
2. [upgrader](https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader) for both **Android and IOS** platform.

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.